# How can I get my accurate location with my phone number using python and geocode?

Tags: python, gps, location, maps, geocode

This is my code for getting the location of my phone number. I get the GPS location in my country, but not exactly where I am. Is there any way I can fix the code to do so?

```
import phonenumbers
import folium
from target import number
from phonenumbers import geocoder
key = 'MY_KEY'    

theNumber = phonenumbers.parse(number)

yourLocation = geocoder.description_for_number(theNumber, "en")

print(yourLocation)


#Other details

from phonenumbers import carrier
service_provider = phonenumbers.parse(number)
print(carrier.name_for_number(service_provider, "en"))

from opencage.geocoder import OpenCageGeocode
geocoder = OpenCageGeocode(key)
query =str(yourLocation)
results = geocoder.geocode(query)
#print(results)

lat = results[0]['geometry']['lat']

long = results[0]['geometry']['lng']

print(lat, long)


myMap = folium.Map(location =[lat, long], zoom_start= 0)

folium.Marker([lat , long], popup=  yourLocation).add_to(myMap)


#html save
myMap.save("myLoc.html")
```

Answer (score 0):

The `phonenumbers` library will only return the country name. Using OpenCage geocoder will translate the country name to the position (the center of the country). At no point does either library or service know where you are.

The code follows a tutorial that is shared on a couple of Youtube video. In the videos the presenter is showing a location which they say it's accurate. Or they say they want to protect themselves and use a differnt location. But it's always the center of the country (usually India or Pakistan).